# Find a key inside a deeply nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have a lot of nested dictionaries, I am trying to find a certain key nested inside somewhere.

e.g. this key is called "fruit". How do I find the value of this key?

Comment: traverse the dictionary and check for key

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@Håvard's recursive solution is probably going to be OK... unless the level of nesting is too high, and then you get a `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`.  To remedy that, you can use the usual technique for recursion removal: keep your own stack of items to examine (as a list that's under your control).  I.e.:

```
def find_key_nonrecursive(adict, key):
  stack = [adict]
  while stack:
    d = stack.pop()
    if key in d:
      return d[key]
    for k, v in d.iteritems():
      if isinstance(v, dict):
        stack.append(v)
```

The logic here is quite close to the recursive answer (except for checking for `dict` in the right way;-), with the obvious exception that the recursive calls are replaced with a `while` loop and `.pop` and `.append` operations on the explicit-stack list, `stack`.

Comment: Do you know exactly what the maximum recursion depth is? From what I understand it would have to be nested at least a 100 deep, but I'm not completely sure.

Comment: @Goose Bumper: `import sys; sys.getrecursionlimit()`. Also, `sys.setrecursionlimit()`

Comment: @gorsky: thanks! For everyone, the recursion limit on my computer is 1000.

Answer (score 2):

(Making some wild guesses about your data structure...)

Do it recursively:

```
def findkey(d, key):
    if key in d: return d[key]
    for k,subdict in d.iteritems():
        val = findkey(subdict, key)
        if val: return val
```

Comment: If any value that's not itself a dict is ever met in the recursion, this approach will try to index it, or call iteritems on that nondict, and thus fail quite peculiarly.

Answer (score 1):

Almost 11 years later... based on [Alex Martelli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95810/alex-martelli) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2524202/3735961) with slight modification, for Python 3 and lists:

```py
def find_key_nonrecursive(adict, key):
    stack = [adict]
    while stack:
        d = stack.pop()
        if key in d:
            return d[key]
        for v in d.values():
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                stack.append(v)
            if isinstance(v, list):
                stack += v
```

Answer (score 0):

Just traverse the dictionary and check for the keys (note the comment in the bottom about the "not found" value).

```
def find_key_recursive(d, key):
  if key in d:
    return d[key]
  for k, v in d.iteritems():
    if type(v) is dict: # Only recurse if we hit a dict value
      value = find_key_recursive(v, key)
      if value:
        return value
  # You may want to return something else than the implicit None here (and change the tests above) if None is an expected value
```

Comment: that's not the way to check type of object. @jathanism: and what are the other possible ways of using recursive function?

Comment: Hmmm... instead of `type(v)` is `dict`, shouldn't you use `instanceof(v, dict)`? The former does not accept subclasses of `dict`. Also, if you check for the existence of `__contains__` instead, your code will also accept other objects that support the "in" operator, not just dicts.

Comment: @Tamás You could also use `isinstance()`, yes. However, dict was a given in this case. The `__contains__` suggestion would not necessarily be right - think about what would happen if you hit a list with that approach, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a handy library for this purpose.

I am iterating over ast of the dict and trying to check if a particular key is present or not.

Do check this out. https://github.com/Agent-Hellboy/trace-dkey

An example from README

```
>>> from trace_dkey import trace
>>> l={'a':{'b':{'c':{'d':{'e':{'f':1}}}}}}
>>> print(trace(l,'f'))
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']]

Now you can query it as l['a']['b']['c']['d']['e']['f']

>>> l['a']['b']['c']['d']['e']['f']
1
```