# Count non-empty end-leafs of a python dicitonary/array data structure - recursive algorithm?

Tags: python, recursion, dictionary, functional-programming, nested

I'm looking for a function to find all the non-empty end-points of a kind of complex dictionary/array structure.  I think that because I don't know the number of nested arrays or their locations, it would have to be recursive, and I just don't entirely get that way of thinking yet.

So for the nested dict:

```
x = {"top": {"middle" : [
                         {"nested": "value"},
                         {"nested":"val2"},
                         {"nested":""}
                        ],
            "last" : [
                         {"nested": [
                            {"first":1,"second":1},
                            {"first":0,"second":""}
                            ]
                            },
                         {"nested": [
                            {"first":1,"second":1},
                            {"first":1,"second":2}
                            ]
                            },
                         {"nested": [
                            {"first":1,"second":1},
                            {"first":"","second":""}
                            ]
                            }
                        ]
            },
      "other":1}
```

and variable "paths" named as follows, where ".XX" designates there is an array (in the style of variety.js):

```
vars = ["top.middle.XX.nested",
        "top.last.XX.nested.XX.first",
        "top.last.XX.nested.XX.second",
        "other"]
```

I'd like a function `f(x,y)` that can return...

```
f(x,"top.middle.XX.nested") = 2/3
f(x,"top.last.XX.nested.XX.first") = 5/6
f(x,"top.last.XX.nested.XX.second") = 4/6
f(x,"other") = 1
```

The problem for me seems to be trying to construct the tree as you go and where to put the counter for nulls.  So, I don't quite understand how to record the counters or do recursion correctly.

Comment: Should maybe `["first":"","second":""]` be `{"first":"","second":""}`?

Comment: Oh, I have a couple problems there, one sec, lemme revise more.

Comment: Next question: if `XX` denotes an array, why is the path `top.last.XX.nested.XX.first` and not `top.last.XX.nested.first`? Being `top.last.XX.nested` a dictionary.

Comment: OK, now it is what I meant---thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: It sounds like you're doing something close to schema validation.  I find tools like `voluptuous` very handy for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this can guide you in the right direction. `byPath` collects the nested dictionary items. Once called, you can basically flatten out the resulting list and check if your condition is met (like `elem != ''` or `not elem` or whatever):

```
x = #your x as posted

def byPath (tree, path):
    try: head, tail = path.split ('.', 1)
    except: return tree [path]

    if head == 'XX': return [byPath (node, tail) for node in tree]
    else: return byPath (tree [head], tail)


print (byPath (x, 'top.middle.XX.nested') )
print (byPath (x, 'top.last.XX.nested.XX.first') )
print (byPath (x, 'top.last.XX.nested.XX.second') )
print (byPath (x, 'other') )
```

**EDIT**: Here the part for actually counting those elements that are not an empty string:

```
def count (result):
    if isinstance (result, list):
        total = 0
        positive = 0
        for e in result:
            r = count (e)
            total += r [1]
            positive += r [0]
        return (positive, total)
    else: return (0 if result == '' else 1, 1)

a = byPath (x, 'top.middle.XX.nested')
b = byPath (x, 'top.last.XX.nested.XX.first')
c = byPath (x, 'top.last.XX.nested.XX.second')
d = byPath (x, 'other')

for x in [a, b, c, d]: print (count (x) )
```

Putting everything together:

```
def f (tree, path):
    return count (byPath (tree, path) )

for path in ['top.middle.XX.nested', 'top.last.XX.nested.XX.first', 'top.last.XX.nested.XX.second', 'other']:
    print (path, f (x, path) )
```

Comment: That was basically it.  Thank you.